# How to use "+=" assignment operator with variable inside animate?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm struggling here to solve this.

http://jsfiddle.net/yhcqfy44/

The animation is supposed to automaticaly scroll top relative to `<span>` height  each time when the scroll bar appears.

I have write this but with no luck:

```
var hheight = $('<span>').height();
var i = 0;
var blackposition;
var square = $('<span></span>').first();
var endless = setInterval(function() {

    if (i % 4 == 0) {
        blackposition = Math.floor(4 * Math.random());
    }

    var math = (blackposition == (i % 4)) ? 0 : 1;

    square.clone().addClass('color_' + math).text((math < 1) ? 'even' + i : 'odd' + i).appendTo('#container');
    i++;

    $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop: '+=' + hheight + 'px'
    }, 1000, 'linear')
}, 500);

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if ($("span").offset().top + $("span").height() < $(window).scrollTop()) {
        $("span").slice(0, 4).remove();
    };
});
```

Is there a solution for doing this ?

Comment: Hint: add `console.log(hheight);` before the part that you think is problematic and look in the console to see what it prints. (In other words, the problem is not where you think it is.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are providing a string for the `scrollTop` property, and JavaScript is just going to treat that as a string and not an operator, apart from that I don't think you can have an operator there so I would try something like this `scrollTop: $(document).height() + 'px'` I think that does what you want it to, take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/yxbj0fen/2/

Basically that just scrolls to the bottom of the document, but you can replace that with another container (e.g. a `div`)

Comment: This do the job for scrolling but doesn't do in a smooth way. It ignore the 'linear' easing.